# How to use PassportJS with Google Calendar (extracting calendar events)

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js, google-calendar-api

I am trying to use PassportJS (Google OAuth Strategy) to authenticate users and extract calendar events once they have logged in and granted permissions.

I've seen the Google Calendar API Node.js Quickstart but they are using it via the OAuth2 client. Is using PassportJS to do what I want possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is definitely possible with Passport. You will need to configure a Google strategy for Passport and include the Calendar API scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar`.

Reference with code: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth2

Then you can use the returned access tokens to make requests to the Calendar API.

Events Resource: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

Comment: Hi Jason thanks for replying! Hmm yes I am using the google-oauth-20 strategy and have also included "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly" in my scope. However, my problem would be that after sending the user to the callbackURL whereby I have passport.authenticate("google"), I am not sure how to use the done (callback) function in passport.use to send the client to another page. Would appreciate some advice on that! Thanks!